# Variable to prevent infinite loop

Tags: excel, infinite-loop, vba

I have a sheet that contains user-defined input and output values. The code will run for most combinations input and output values, but for some it will return the data I am asking for, and then enter an infinite loop.

I was thinking that adding a variable and couple codes of line where the variable counts the number of times the loop runs through the entire row. Once the value of the variable equals 2x the number of runs, it exits the sub.

Is there a proper way to write this code and is it possible?

Thank you in advance

```
Sub SuperNova()

Dim Startval As String
Dim Endval As String
Dim LastRow As Long                 'SAVE THIS - DON'T TOUCH
Dim Rng As range                    'SAVE THIS - DON'T TOUCH
Dim Output As Long                  'SAVE THIS - DON'T TOUCH
Dim NewStart As String


Dim Val As String
Dim Valnew As String

LastRow = Worksheets(3).range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Output = 2
Startval = Worksheets(3).Cells(7, "AC")
NewStart = Startval
Line1:
For X = 7 To LastRow

    Val = Worksheets(3).Cells(X, 2)       'if i set the variables equal to a string, do i need the GetSingleFromString function?

    Endval = Worksheets(3).Cells(7, "AD")


If Val = Endval And Valnew = Endval Then

Exit Sub

ElseIf StrComp(Val, NewStart) = 0 Then
    Worksheets(4).Cells(Output, 1).Value = _
          Worksheets(3).Cells(X, 1).Value
            Output = Output + 1
    Worksheets(4).Cells(Output, 1).Value = _
          Worksheets(3).Cells(X, 1).Value
            Output = Output + 1
        Valnew = Worksheets(3).Cells(X, 3)
        NewStart = Valnew
End If

Next X

If Valnew = Endval Then
Exit Sub
Else
GoTo Line1
End If

End Sub
```

Here is my excel sheet: Enter a value from Column B in cell "AC7" and a value from Column C into cell "AD7" and then run the code and should paste in Sheet4. Combinations such as "1 to 4" will work. but if I give AC7 a value of "10" and AD7 a value of "6" it returns the values in column A that I need, but then runs into an infinite loop and crashes.

[image]

Comment: I don't see where it could infinite loop. How do you call your method ?
Do you fear the infinite loop on your "SuperNova()" method ?

Comment: I've updated my question with an excel sheet and description of what causes an infinite loops. 

Combinations such as "1 to 4" will work. but if I give AC7 a value of "10" and AD7 a value of "6" it returns the values in column A that I need, but then runs into an infinite loop and crashes.

Comment: ahhh... the dreaded GoTo...

Comment: It is certainly possible to put a loop-counter in a loop and use it to break out of the loop to prevent it from being an infinite loop -- but it is a bad idea to do so as a band-aid to cover up a logic flaw. Find and fix the flaw instead.

Comment: The code works and returns the values asked for, but I can't figure out why it keeps looking for values after it has already found them

Comment: I don't understand your code... It looks like "hooo, such a brillant idea", but if you want to maintain it in time, add a lot of comments in it (cause in several month it will looks like "what was I doing here...")
You should set a breakpoint and execute your code step by step (with F8), it's the easiest way to find your infinite loop